# Use assertThat function of AssertJ in ifPresent() of Java Optional

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, assertj

How can I remove try-catch block for the `assertThat` in the `ifPresent()`? The compiler gives me only one option for using `assertThat` in `ifPresent()`, which is to surround it with try-catch block. Throw the exception again is not allowed too.

```
@Test
public void testPostRequestThenSaveResponse()
        throws HttpStatusCodeException, JsonProcessingException, IllegalArgumentException, IOException {
    // Should success.
    try {
        ServiceAssignmentImpl.httpPostDeliveryOrder(url, token, sod, customerSite, customer, item, uom, driver)
                .ifPresent((deliveryOrderResponse) -> {
                    // increase DO number for next test.
                    deliveryOrderNum++;
                    DeliveryOrderResponse savedDOResponse = deliveryOrderResponseRepository
                            .save(deliveryOrderResponse);
                    DeliveryOrderResponse fetchedDOResponse = deliveryOrderResponseRepository
                            .findOne(savedDOResponse.getId());                      
                    try {
                        assertThat(json.write(fetchedDOResponse))
                                .isEqualTo(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(deliveryOrderResponse));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
        // need getResponseBodyAsString() to see detail error message.
        System.out.println("** HttpStatusCodeException: " + e.getResponseBodyAsString());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't create an incremental variable between tests. Tests should be isolated from one another

Comment: @OneCricketeer , thanks for advice. I am sending HTTP Post request to API that does not belong to me, which requires unique delivery number, so I record the latest available number into a text file. I think the mocking of API is not optimal in this case as the documentation of the API is pretty unclear. Is there any other option for this scenario ?

Comment: Non integration tests shouldn't depend on external resources, so, yes, mock the response. Even integration tests should use a Wiremock server rather than the real endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.get()`, your test should not pass if the response is not present, so there is no need to make it conditional.

I've adapted your code as best I could without a MCVE.

```
    @Test
    public void testPostRequestThenSaveResponse()
            throws HttpStatusCodeException, JsonProcessingException, IllegalArgumentException, IOException {
        // Should success.
        try {
            var = deliveryOrderResponseServiceAssignmentImpl.httpPostDeliveryOrder(url, token, sod, customerSite, customer, item, uom, driver).get()
                   
             // increase DO number for next test.
             deliveryOrderNum++;
             DeliveryOrderResponse savedDOResponse = deliveryOrderResponseRepository
                                .save(deliveryOrderResponse);
             DeliveryOrderResponse fetchedDOResponse = deliveryOrderResponseRepository
                                .findOne(savedDOResponse.getId());  
             assertThat(json.write(fetchedDOResponse))
                                    .isEqualTo(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(deliveryOrderResponse));
                     
        } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
            // need getResponseBodyAsString() to see detail error message.
            System.out.println("** HttpStatusCodeException: " + e.getResponseBodyAsString());
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should ideally save the optional to its own variable, then assert that it is present, **then** call get